# How to get value by key from JSON?

Tags: java, json

JSON looks like:

```
{  
   "cover":"blabla.jpg",
   "content":[  
      {  
         "article":"article_text",
         "document":"document_text"
      }
   ]
}
```

I know how to get `"cover"`:

```
JSONObject json = new JsonObject(jsonStr);
json.get("cover");
```

But how can I get value by `"article"` key?

Answer (score 20):

You can try something like this:

```
yourJSonObject.getJSONObject("cover").getJSONObject("content").getJSONObject("article");
```

Comment: is there any way to convert same to Hashmap and travers like this.?

Answer (score 14):

Oh, i did it. Thanks.

```
json.getJSONArray("content").getJSONObject(0).getString("article")
```

Answer (score -1):

`"content"` in that position it´s just a String, so at first place you have to create a new `JSONObject` from that String and then you can access to his properties like this

```
JSONObject content = new JSONObject(yourJSonObject.getString("content"));
String article = content.getString("article");
```