# Rest assured extracting values in json response in java

Tags: java, rest-assured

How can i extract names in the following JSON response using java?

```
{
  "type": "students",
  "values": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "name": "Raj"
          
    },
    {
      "id": "456",
      "name": "Rahul"
         
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812881/how-to-get-value-by-key-from-json/36813005).

Comment: Will that return only one value or all values of names? I need to extract all values of names in this case Raj ,Rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all `names`:

```
Response res = ...;
List<String> names = res.jsonPath().getList("values.name");
System.out.println(names); //[Raj, Rahul]
```