# How to access an int inside of a array in a JSON file

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a JSON file holding students name, id, and grades. I managed to print the name and id, but cannot figure out how to access the grades ("score").

Part of my JSON file (3 other students) :

```
"Name": "Abstract Data Types",
  "CRN": "14607",
  "Capacity": 24,
  "Code": "cs241",
  "Time": "13:50",
  "Number of Sections": 1,
  "Students": [
    {
      "name": "David",
      "id": "987654321",
      "course works":[
        {
          "name": "q1",
          "score": 2
        },{
          "name": "q2",
          "score": 10
        },{
          "name": "q3",
          "score": 10
        },{
          "name": "midterm",
          "score": 89
        },{
          "name": "final",
          "score": 95
        }
      ]
    }
```

So, I managed to print "name" and "id" with :

```
for (JsonValue value : studentsArray) {
            String name = value.asJsonObject().getString("name");
            String id = value.asJsonObject().getString("id");


            if (value.asJsonObject().getString("name").equalsIgnoreCase(commandInput)) {
                System.out.println("Name: " + name + " | " + "ID: " + id + " | ");
            }
        }
```

I cannot figure out how to now print q1-final grades. I keep receiving errors saying the value is null.

I have tried just doing something like:

```
int q1 = value.asJsonObject().getInt("score");
```

hoping it would at at least print all of the grades (and not just quiz 1, like I need), but instead gave the error:
Cannot invoke "javax.json.JsonNumber.intValue()" because the return value of "org.glassfish.json.JsonObjectBuilderImpl$JsonObjectImpl.getJsonNumber(String)" is null

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812881/how-to-get-value-by-key-from-json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get value by key from JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812881/how-to-get-value-by-key-from-json)

Comment: @KuldeepYadav Yup. Got it now, thanks.